# Как сделать время (сегодня, вчера,дата), чтоб при обновлении ресурса не менялось?

Tags: ios, swift, дата, uitableview

Столкнулся  с проблемой при обновлении ресурса , время указанное в старом событие меняется на новое , при парсинге.Подскажите что это может быть. Мне подсказывали и я вот так его изобразил, где я допустил ошибку.Вот мой код:

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let sportCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "sportCell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell


                if segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0  {


                 let insertRow = (soccerString.count - 1) - indexPath.row
                 let soccer = soccerString[insertRow]

                sportCell.matchLabel.text = soccer.matchS
                soccerString[insertRow].imagePrS.getDataInBackground {(data, error) in
                sportCell.imageMatch.image = error == nil ? UIImage(data: data!) : nil
                    }
                }
                else if segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {

                let newIndex = (basketString.count - 1) - indexPath.row
                let basket = basketString[newIndex]
                sportCell.matchLabel.text = basket.matchB
                basketString[newIndex].imagePrB.getDataInBackground {(data, error) in
                    sportCell.imageMatch.image = error == nil ? UIImage(data: data!) : nil

                }

                }  else if segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 2 {

                 let newInt = (tennisString.count - 1) - indexPath.row
                sportCell.matchLabel.text = tennisString[newInt].matchT

                tennisString[newInt].imagePrT.getDataInBackground {(data, error) in
                        sportCell.imageMatch.image = error == nil ? UIImage(data: data!) : nil

                }

         }



            sportCell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.none

            let date = Date()
            let calendar = Calendar.current



            let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

            dateFormatter.dateStyle = .short
            dateFormatter.timeStyle = .short
            dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "ru_UA")
            dateFormatter.doesRelativeDateFormatting = true


            if let today = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: 0, to: date) {

                sportCell.dataSave.text = dateFormatter.string(from: today)

            } else if let yesterday = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: -1, to: date) {

                sportCell.dataSave.text = dateFormatter.string(from:yesterday)
            } else {
                sportCell.dataSave.text = dateFormatter.string(from: date)

            }

            sportCell.setNeedsLayout()
            sportCell.layoutIfNeeded()

            return sportCell
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы сначала присваиваете текущую дату переменной date:

```
let date = Date()
```

А потом исходя из нее, создаете переменные today и yesterday. Вы никак не работаете с датой, приходящей из soccerString.

Comment: Подскажите как сделать, или пример наглядно?

Comment: @AleksandrIlin Для этого надо знать какие поля есть у объекта soccerString[insertRow]

Comment: Так я все указал.И сделал в конце время , для всех сегментов.

Comment: @AleksandrIlin Я не вижу где вы это указали. Я вижу только использование текущей даты.

Comment: Тогда покажи мне по подробнее если тут вопросы с ответами , а то не могу понять как сделать.Очень буду благодарен.